# Positive measurable function multiplied with indicator function is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose a measured space (X, $A$, $\mu$) and a A-measurable function: $f: X\longrightarrow [0,\infty]$ on X. I have to show, that $\int_A$ f =:$\nu(A)$ defines a measure. $\nu(\emptyset)$ = 0 is easily shown.
However, I am stuck with: $ \nu(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (A_n))$ =  $\int_{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (A_n)}fd\nu$ = $\int_{X} 1_{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}} fd\nu$ = $\int_{X} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f1_{A_n}d\nu$. If I could show, that $f1_{A_n}$ is A-measurable for every n, then I have a lemma, that allows to me to bring the sum out of the integral, so that I'm done. Therefore the question:
How can I show, that a function multiplied with an indicator function is (A)-measurable?

$1_{A_n}$ is the indicator function and of course all $A_n$ are disjoint to each other.

Comment: More generally, the product of two nonnegative measurable functions is measurable.  This is true with the convention $0\times\infty = 0$ and $a \times \infty = \infty$ for $0 < a \le \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{x: f(x)1_{A_n} (x) <a\}=\emptyset$ if $a \leq 0$ and $\{x: f(x)1_{A_n} (x) <a\}=\{x\in A_n: f(x) <a\} \cup A_n^{c}$ of $a >0$.  In either case $\{x: f(x)1_{A_n} (x) <a\} \in \mathcal A$. This is true for every real number $a$. Also $\{x: f1_{A_n}=\infty\} =A_n \cap \{x: f(x)=\infty\} \in \mathcal A$. So $f1_{A_n}$ is measurable.

According to the definition you gave in the comments below a subset $B$ of $[0,\infty]$ is measurable if and only if it is either a Borel subset of $[0,\infty)$ or it has the form $\{\infty\} \cup C$ where $C$ is a Borel subset of $[0,\infty)$. Since $f_n^{-1} (\{\infty\} \cup C)=f_n^{-1}(C) \cup f_n^{-1} (\{\infty\})$ it is enough to show that $f_n^{-1}(C) $ and $f_n^{-1} (\{\infty\})$  are measurable for all Borel sets $C$ in $[0,\infty)$. But the latter condition follow from the fact that $f^{-1} [0,a)$ is measurable for each real number $a \in [0,\infty)$.

Comment: For case of a>0: Could I also write ${x:f(x)\ 1_{A_n}(x) <= a }$   instead of a<0? Because my function can also obtain $\infty$.

Comment: @Mathpiano I have edited my answer

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense!

Comment: I'm sorry, but i might need another proof. Interesing part you've showedis that for every $ [0,a[ \subseteq [0,\infty]:  (f1_{A_{n}})^{-1} ([0,a]) \in A $. However, we (our script) did not define an $\sigma -algebra$ on $[0,\infty]$, where all possible intervals are in that space. Even if we look into the Borel-set of $[0,\infty]$: We didn't define one for that, such that all intervals are in there. So I can't say, that $[0,a] \in \sigma -algebra$ on $ [0,\infty]$. We only defined the borels set of whole $R$ and whole $R \cup {\infty} \cup  -{\infty}$, where all kind of intervals are in there.

Comment: It is your job to tell me how you define measurability for a functioin which takes infinite values. The definition I know says $f$ is measaurable if $f^{-1}(A)$ is measurable for each Borel set  $A$ in $\mathbb R$ and $f^{-1}(\{\infty\}), f^{-1}(\{-\infty\})$ are measurable.  @Mathpiano

Comment: Your given definition is true, if we are looking at a function $f: X \rightarrow R \cup {-\infty } \cup {\infty}$.  In general, if $f: X\rightarrow Y$ with A and B as $\sigma$-algebra, we need to show: $f^{-1} (C) \in A $for every  $C\in B$. In that case, f is A-B measurable. We actually defined a borel set of [0,$\infty$], which are all intervals, whose intersection with $[0,\infty[$ are in the borel set of [0,$\infty$[, but we did not define, what the borel set of $[0,\infty[$ particulary is...

Comment: @Mathpiano I have edited my answer.